# IllegalArgumentException on any functions with GeoDataFrame

Tags: geopandas

I'm trying to do anything with my GeoDataFrame that I'm importing from the Census website, but when I try to dissolve or overlay with other data frames I get:

pygeos.GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing

It won't every overlay itself which is weird. I've exploded it to get rid of the multi polygon and buffered the three invalid polygons, but I'm lost. New to geopandas but I can general feel my way around these things. Any help would be appreciated.

Is my installed package the issue?

Download [this](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_cd116_20m.zip) file

```py
>>> import geopandas as gpd
>>> SHAPE_URL = 'https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2018/shp/cb_2018_us_cd116_20m.zip'
>>> cd = gpd.read_file(SHAPE_URL)
>>> cd.dissolve()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 1538, in dissolve
    g = self.groupby(group_keys=False, **groupby_kwargs)[self.geometry.name].agg(
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 259, in aggregate
    return self._python_agg_general(func, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1173, in _python_agg_general
    result, counts = self.grouper.agg_series(obj, f)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 691, in agg_series
    return self._aggregate_series_pure_python(obj, func)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py", line 741, in _aggregate_series_pure_python
    res = func(group)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 1160, in <lambda>
    f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/geodataframe.py", line 1535, in merge_geometries
    merged_geom = block.unary_union
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/base.py", line 728, in unary_union
    return self.geometry.values.unary_union()
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/array.py", line 652, in unary_union
    return vectorized.unary_union(self.data)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/geopandas/_vectorized.py", line 892, in unary_union
    return _pygeos_to_shapely(pygeos.union_all(data))
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygeos/decorators.py", line 80, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/joefedorowicz/Development/virtualenvs/briefcase/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pygeos/set_operations.py", line 388, in union_all
    result = lib.unary_union(collections, **kwargs)
pygeos.GEOSException: IllegalArgumentException: Argument must be Polygonal or LinearRing
```

Comment: can you provide an [mre]? if the shapefile is from census you should be able to give us all the code and data to reproduce the problem. thanks!

Comment: Added a link to the shape file and some code.

Comment: How are you reading in the shapefile?  dissolve works on the linked file for me.

Comment: Thanks for the updates - please always include a [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when reporting errors - it includes a ton of info that is really helpful in helping us (and you) debug! :)

Comment: @DNy just using read_file to the shp. Also, traceback above.

Comment: this works fine for me using geopandas v0.9.0. can you try reinstallling geopandas and, if the problem is reproducible, give us the spec for your environment and tell us more about how you install it?

Comment: works fine for me geopandas 0.10.2